# how to delete element inside element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#movieForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var symbol = $("#movieInput").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=x78wnu3hc3ve7amqeffws693&q=' + symbol,
      dataType:'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        for(i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++) {
          $("#movieTable").append("<tr><td><strong>" + data.movies[i].title + "</strong></td></tr>");
          console.log(data.movies[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

how i can clear table input when i search for next word its keep adding search over and over

Comment: Here, which element are you talking about??? The input, right?!

Comment: And then, you want to reset its value or what? If ya, use answer below

Comment: element or value bro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to clear `$("#movieInput")` element, try like this

```
$("#movieInput").val("");
```

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#movieForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var symbol = $("#movieInput").val("");
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/  …; + symbol, dataType:'
                    jsonp ',
              success: function(data) {
              for(i = 0; i < data.movies.length;   i++) 
              { $("#movieTable").html("<tr><td><strong>" + data.movies[i].title + "</strong></td>  </tr>"); console.log(data.movies[i]);
            } 
                   }

                   });
    });
});
```

use `$("#movieTable").html(` instead of `$("#movieTable").append(`

Comment: sorry actually i am trying to clear input table

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer.